# Want to show unique values only using d3.js not working

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have  large dataset with the same detector having multiple occurrence. There are also many detectors. I want to fill a combobox with the unique detectors only. 
I am using the following code:

```
d3.select("#detectors")
    .selectAll("option")
    .data(d3.map(data, function(d) {
            return d.code;
        })
        .keys())
    .enter()
    .append("option")
    .text(function(d) {
        return d;
    }).attr("value", function(d) {
        return d;
    });
```

But its not showing unique detector codes. Rather the combobox is being filled with number from 1 to ongoing.
How can I do my desired goal. My sample simple dataset is

```
var data=[{"code":5222,"date":3-4-2015},{"code":5222,"date":3-6-2015},{"code":5222,"date":3-7-2015},];
```

The data has in real a large number of detectors with unique code. I want to show these unique codes in the combobox. For the above case there will be only one 5222 in the options

Comment: how about reformatting your code examples so they're readable

Comment: I am not being able to do so

Comment: The code you have posted seems to work as you want it to, see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ff6doad1/)

Comment: That's my wonder also. Why doesn't it work in my project. its just showing 1..N

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to use [nest()](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#-nest).

```
var nest = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) { return d.code; })
  .entries(data);
```

That will create a new array with each code only once and an object of all the objects that have that value.

**Edit**

```
var data=[{"code":5222,"date":3-4-2015},{"code":5222,"date":3-6-2015},{"code":5222,"date":3-7-2015}];

var nest = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) { return d.code;})
  .entries(data);

d3.select("#detectors").selectAll("option")
  .data(nest)
  .enter()
    .append("option")
    .text(function(d){ return d.key;})
    .attr("value",function(d){return d.key;});
```

This code works for me with no errors

Comment: Nest returns an array of objects (`[object,object]`) so you need to modify your code to access the data, inside the 'object'.  The object will have the form `{ key: 5222, values: Array[3] }`, so you will have to `return d.key` not just `d`.

Answer (score 1):

You could solve this problem using **d3.set()** method: https://github.com/d3/d3-collection/blob/master/README.md#sets.

The code will be:

```
var data=[{"code":5222,"date":3-4-2015},{"code":5222,"date":3-6-2015},{"code":5222,"date":3-7-2015},];

var Unique = d3.set(data, function(d) {return d.code});
```

Unique returns only '5222', as you expected.

Please, note that d3 converts data to strings in this case, so it might be the case you would need to convert them back to numbers.